# Merging S57 NOAA ENC Depth Contours (DEPCNT) for Different Scale Level Maps

Tags: postgis, noaa, s-57

I have a challenge merging ENC map data from S57 to derive single maps comprising the most accurate data available. For example: I have a scale level 5 map **US5FL25M** which holds more accurate data than the underlying **US4FL20M** ENC map. So far so good. However, I have noticed that sometimes there is data missing, this is just an example.

In the following 2 screenshots you can see a) the depth contours (DEPCNT) of the aforementioned scale level 5 map and in b) the depth contours of the scale level 4 map. You will notice the missing information in former whereas it exists in the latter. I am wondering how I could merge this data to get the best of both worlds, i.e. keeping all scale level 5 information available but filling up parts of the map which are missing (there are blue contours in the lower part of the scale level 4 map which the scale level 5 map obviously does not show). Currently I take the boundary of the scale level 5 map, delete everything in the scale level 4 map which intersects and "embed" the scale level 5 into the the scale level 4 map. This is were I loose information. Is there any other approach to do this or is there information in the s57 data I could make use of?

*a) Scale level 5 Map (highlighted yellow), depth contours visualized red*
[image: Scale level 5 Map]

*b) Scale level 4 Map (green boundary) with the Scale level 5 Map floating over it (hashed black), depth contours visualized blue*
[image: Scale level 4 Map]